# Can you convert smells to variables?

Tags: nose, chromatography

Is there a way to map smells to numerical values of different variables?

I.e. With RGB colours, each colour is made up of numerical values from 0-255. For example, red is (255,0,0), and yellow is (255,255,0). Is there a way to do this with smells. I.e, the smell of Candy is (140,70,255), and the smell of grass is (255,34,27)? How many different sets of numbers (like red, green and blue) would you need, and what would they represent?

Comment: Given that the human genome has genes for about 700-800 different smell receptors (very ballpark from the top of my head), you'd probably need around that many numbers to encode smells into numbers